# Update content in single div, with all div names the same

Tags: jquery

Seem to be stuck trying to only update images in a selected div, when all the div names are the same.

```
<div class="collapse">img img img img img</div>
<div class="collapse">img img img img img img img</div>
<div class="collapse">img img img </div>
<div class="collapse">img img img img img img</div>
```

I have the data of the images set inside a data-src tag, and when the div gets expanded, it loads the images. However, since the divs have the same class name, when it goes to load the images in the expanded div, it loads all the images in all the collapse divs.

```
    $(function() {
      $('.collapse img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
         return this.getAttribute('data-src');
      });
    });
```

This is the code inside my expand code, how can it be changed to only load the images in the currently selected div?

Edit - Expand Code:

```
$.fn.toggler = function(options) {
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.toggler.defaults, options);

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.wrapInner('<a style="display:block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="#" title="Expand/Collapse" />');
    if (o.initShow) {$(o.initShow).addClass('shown');}
    $this.next(o.cllpsEl + ':not(.shown)').hide();
    return this.each(function() {
      var container;
      (o.container) ? container = o.container : container = 'html';
      if ($this.next('div.shown').length) { $this.closest(container).find('.shown').show().prev().find('a').addClass('open'); }
      $(this).click(function() {



        $(function() {
          $('.collapse img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
             return this.getAttribute('data-src');
          });
        });



        $(this).find('a').toggleClass('open').end().next(o.cllpsEl)[o.method](o.speed);
        return false;
    });
});};
```

Edit 2 - How the div gets expanded. Sorry, still pretty new to this site. Should have given more info.

This is the javascript at the top of the page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("span.expand").toggler({method: "toggle", speed: 0});
    });
  </script>
```

The span that gets clicked to expand the div:

```
<span class="expand">&nbsp;</span>
```

The span is set up in css to show an image as the background.

Edit: Found the solution.

I placed:

```
$(this).find('a').toggleClass('open').end().next(o.cllpsEl)[o.method](o.speed);
```

Above the show image code, so that it would toggle it open first before trying to load the images, and changed the load image code to:

```
    $(function() {
      $this.closest(container).find('.collapse:visible img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
         return this.getAttribute('data-src');
      });
    });
```

Thanks all :P

Comment: How are your divs being expanded? How can you tell which div is selected?

Comment: Where is your expand div code ?

Comment: Pom, what has this to do with PHP? I took the liberty to remove the tag, this seems purely client-sided javascript to me.

Comment: Edited with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that you are handling your expansion by clicking the div in question

```
$(".collapse").click(function() {
    // code that handles expanding 
    // ....

    $(this).children("img").attr('src', function(index, src) {
        return this.getAttribute('data-src');
    });
});
```

Comment: The code provided uses `wrapInner` to wrap the children of the `this` element, so the image elements are most likely not children of the `.collapse` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You're attaching the event handler using `$()`, which is shorthand for "when the document is ready" and then saying "for every .collapse img, do this". There's nothing there that suggests anything being "selected". Now, suppose by "selected" you mean "clicked". In that case, you'd want to do something like:

```
$(function() {
  $('.collapse').click(function () {
    $(this).children('img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
     return this.getAttribute('data-src');
    });
  });
});
```

Now, every div.collapse that gets clicked runs the code to set the src of the images.

(I'm guessing this is still not quite what you mean, but it's probably closer)

Comment: The code provided uses `wrapInner` to wrap the children of the `this` element, so the image elements are most likely not children of the `.collapse` elements.

Comment: In that case, replacing .children() with .find() would probably do. Anyway, OP changed so much that my answer is probably WAY out of date. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.toggler = function(options) {
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.toggler.defaults, options);

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.wrapInner('<a style="display:block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="#" title="Expand/Collapse" />');
    if (o.initShow) {$(o.initShow).addClass('shown');}
    $this.next(o.cllpsEl + ':not(.shown)').hide();
    return this.each(function() {
      var container;
      (o.container) ? container = o.container : container = 'html';
      if ($this.next('div.shown').length) { $this.closest(container).find('.shown').show().prev().find('a').addClass('open'); }
      $(this).click(function() {


          //right here `this` refers to the same this from above: `$(this).click(...`
          $.each($(this).find('img'), function () {

              //right here `this` refers to the current image, since we are looping over all the images
              $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
          });


        $(this).find('a').toggleClass('open').end().next(o.cllpsEl)[o.method](o.speed);
        return false;
    });
});};
```

I am assuming that `this` is one of the `.collapse` elements, in which case we are finding the image within the clicked `.collapse` element and only altering it's `src` attribute.

Note that you don't need the `$(function () {})` (`document.ready` event handler) inside your code. It should be used to initialize plugins like this.

Comment: `$(this).find('img').attr('data-src')` this would reference the div and not the image. It needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function.

Comment: I see your point. I wrote it at first thinking there was one image per div. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When expanding you could use the `$(this)` keyword within the expand code and get the currently expanded node.

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src', function() {  return $(this).data('src');  });
```